# How do I delete characters in a string up to a certain point in classic asp?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a string that at any point may or may not contain one or more / characters. I'd like to be able to create a new string based on this string. The new string would include every character after the very last / in the original string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're wanting the file name from a URL. In any case, it's the same function. The key is using the InStrRev function to find the first / char, but starting from the right. Here's the function:

```
Function GetFilename(URL)
   Dim I
   I = InStrRev(URL, "/")
   If I > 0 Then
      GetFilename = Mid(URL, I + 1)
   Else
      GetFilename = URL
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: That's not VBScript, it's VB. It won't work in classic ASP. (If you want I can fix it for you)

Comment: I think I know the error, but I don't have classic ASP setup on my system to check. If you want to correct it, please feel free. Thanks.

Comment: Well, on closer look it was only the variable types that don't exist in VBScript, the rest was fine. You still have one flaw, when the URL doesn't have any slash (e.g. "Page.aspx") it will return Empty while I think it should be returning the whole URL. Anyhow this is all pure VBScript so you can just create file with `.vbs` extension on your machine, edit it with Notepad and execute - Windows has internal VBScript engine.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was it, but wasn't positive and couldn't test. Added the functionality to return the whole URL if no / is found. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Split it up into parts and get the last part:

```
a = split("my/string/thing", "/")
wscript.echo a(ubound(a))
```

note: Not safe when the string is empty.